# Will holding a reference to a string-property of an Entity Framework object keep it from being collected by the GC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection

I load entries from my MySQL database with entity framework, and create a new object where I send in the string-properties from the database-object into my constructor and return the new object (with no direct references to any database-classes).

When I'm running a memory-profiler I see loads of these database-entities held in memory. Is this correct or is there any way to get around this?

```
var eoList = new List<EnterpriseObject>();
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var infos = context.tableName.Where(dbObject => dbObject.Date > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList();

    foreach (var dbObject in infos)
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeEnum> enums = dbObject.enumStrings.Select(enumString => enumString.ToSomeEnum()); // Added in edited, as this was the problem, this IEnumerable was a property in the EnterpriseObject and somehow kept references to the DbObjects. Changing the property to a List<SomeEnum> fixed my problem.
        var entepriseObject = new EnterpriseObject(dbObject.Name, dbObject.Date, enums);
        eoList.Add(enterpiseObject);
    }
}
return eoList;
```

Would the code above actually keep all the references in "infos" in memory as long as the "eoList" object is referenced?

If so, is there a better way of doing this to avoid this problem?

Tomas

EDIT: For anyone else looking at this problem, check my added line of code which was the problem.

Comment: `Would the code above actually keep all the references in "infos" in memory as long as the "eoList" object is referenced?` No. In the debugger, `infos` is likely being kept alive until the end of the method (a `Release` build will result in it being eligible for GC earlier than that). You should remove the `ToList` in your code example above - and consider projecting just the columns you need (`Name` and `Date`) to avoid unnecessary data passing over the wire.

Comment: `I see loads of these database-entities held in memory` How many do you see? Taking up how much memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `.Name` and `.Date` return unsurprising types<sup>1</sup>, then no, your `EnterpriseObject` has no knowledge that those values came from a `dbObject` and won't be (itself) responsible for keeping them alive.

I would expect a good memory profiler can tell you how objects are *rooted*, that is "what's keeping this object alive?". If not, you can take a memory dump and use WinDbg/SOS to answer that same question. Don't *speculate* about what the roots might be.

Searching on `WinDBg`, `SOS` and `gcroot` might net you some results, nobody seems to have written any new articles on it for about 10 years or so though. There's also a `VisualSOS.Extension` for Visual Studio that looks like it'd do a good job but I've not tried it myself.

---

<sup>1</sup>I.e. it would be surprising to discover that `Date` returns `this` and that the type also supports an implicit conversion from itself to `DateTime` so that the `Where` lambda compiles :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes my profiler does indeed tells me how it's rooted, and it claims by EnterpriseObject holds a Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator<DbType, OtherEnterpiseType>.

My EnterpriseObject has a property with type IEnumerable<OtherEnterpriseType> where OtherEnterpriseType is an enum parsed from a string-property of the DbObject.

Comment: So the problem seemed to be the IEnumerable<OtherEnterpriseType> property that somehow kept references (probably because some lazy evaluation).
When I changed it from an IEnumerable to a List<> the references are not there anymore.